processing all files in directory recursively in Apache Camel Route as soon as a done file exists
In Apache Camel xml I want to process a each file in a directory recursively when a certain file indicates that all files have been successfully generated (@see mock:result). When all files have been processed I want to do some cleanup (@see mock:finished)
1st try
What I wanted is basically something like this:
    <route id="test1">
        <from uri="file://target/test-classes/generated?recursive=true&amp;doneFileName=./done-generation.txt"/>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${exchangeProperty.CamelBatchComplete}</simple>
                <to uri="mock:finished"/>
            </when>
        </choice>
    </route>

This solution doesn't work as I expected. It only returns the files in the same directory as the done-generation file. (It would work if I remove the doneFileName option but obviously this doesn't wait for the files to be fully generated)
2nd try
After a lot of tries the closest I got to work was this:
        <route id="testSimples">
            <!--<from uri="file://target/test-classes/generated?fileName=done-generation.txt"/>-->
            <from uri="scheduler:mockScheduler?delay=10000?"/>
            <setBody>
                <simple resultType="Integer">-1</simple>
            </setBody>
            <loop doWhile="true" >
                <simple>${body} != null</simple>
                <setBody>
                    <simple >${null}</simple>
                </setBody>
                <pollEnrich timeout="1" aggregationStrategy="groupedMessageAggregationStrategy">
                    <constant>file://target/test-classes/generated?repeatCount=1&amp;noop=true&amp;recursive=true&amp;initialDelay=0&amp;antExclude=gen/></constant>
                </pollEnrich>
            </loop>
            <split aggregationStrategy="groupedMessageAggregationStrategy2">
                <simple>${exchangeProperty.CamelGroupedExchange}</simple>
                <to uri="mock:result"/>
            </split>
            <to uri="mock:finished"/>
        </route>

But this solution only works with an inital consumer not being file. (scheduler in this case) as soon as I change to scheduler it only returns one time the done-generation file instead of all the files
Would anybody have a hint on how to achieve what I want? I would prefer an option in pure xml but if some additional processors are needed that would also be fine.
